# Accessing fields from a list of structs using a foreach loop

Tags: c#, list, loops

For anyone stumbling on to this question. Unfortunately it was down-voted by over eager commentators before I got the chance to amend it with the error message, which is now included. The question still stands and so do the answers.

I have a struct like this

```
public struct note{

    public note (double SampleTime, string Label)
    {
        sampleTime = (float)SampleTime;
        label = Label;
    }
    float sampleTime;
    string label;
}
```

I've declared a list which will be comprised of new note structs

```
public List<note> notesList;
```

And in some other method initialize it and then add data

```
notesList = new List<note>();
notesList.Add(new note(Convert.ToDouble(seperatefields[0]),seperatefields[1]));
```

I'd then like to create a foreach loop and read out the contents of my list

```
    foreach(note n in notesList){

        Debug.Log (n.sampleTime);
    }
```

However this won't work.

> `rhythmGameUtilityReadFile.note.sampleTime' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Thanks

Jim

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't help us - in what way does it not work?

Comment: You're right. I should of read the error in the console. Thanks for looking anyway `rhythmGameUtilityReadFile.note.sampleTime' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: Downvoting my question isn't helping either. It was quite easy to add this and the question still might help others.

Comment: Rather than complaining about downvotes, you should learn from the comments you get and post a better question next time. Although some people down-vote (mainly questions) relatively easily, a post meeting the basic SO expectations is rarely downvoted. If you still don't understand why you keep getting downvotes, you should take a (deeper) look at the help pages and/or read other questions to understand what you are doing wrong. Also remember that this is not just about you, but also about future readers: do some effort by your own, make sure that this hasn't been asked before, etc.

Comment: My post was useful for others and with the inclusion of the error message was fairly well presented with tags, error messages, clear subject and example code. I don't get my posts down-voted ever, this was the first time and incorrectly so.

Also remember varocarbas - If you aren't supplying anything useful towards the question but commenting on stack overflow etiquette then I suggest you make sure you read the post fully. If you have a suggestion for an edit please say. If you do that I'm sure you'll enjoy Stack Overflow!http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 2):

Default access modifier in C# is `private`. Your `struct` has only private fields, so you cannot access them outside of it. Add public properties to get the values:

```
public struct Note
{
    float sampleTime;
    string label;

    public Note(double SampleTime, string Label)
    {
        sampleTime = (float)SampleTime;
        label = Label;
    }

    public float SampleTime { get { return sampleTime; } }
    public string Label { get { return label; } }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have any public field in you struct.

Comment: Thats exactly right, thanks! The error was `rhythmGameUtilityReadFile.note.sampleTime' is inaccessible due to its protection level. I should of checked that.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the field isn't accessible.

Make it public, and make it a property while you're at it.

```
public struct note
{
    public note (double sampleTime, string label)
    {
        SampleTime = (float)sampleTime;
        Label = label;
    }

    public float SampleTime { get; private set; }
    public string Label { get; private set; }
}
```